# how to return an ajax request response(data ) to client in cakephp 2.3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

i am trying to add to database using ajax in cakephp 2.3, but don't know how to set the response but to the user with additional data which i would have used

```
$this->set()
```

for a normal request
the view file :

```
        echo $this->Form->create(); echo $this->Form->input('name');
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
    echo $this->Form->input('phone');
    echo $this->Form->input('message');
echo $this->Js->submit('Send Enquiry', array(
    'before' => $this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
    'success' => $this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
             'update' => '#success',
              'async' => true
               ));echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

and the controller function is:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Contact->create();
        if ($this->Contact->save($this->request->data)) {

            if($this->request->isAjax()){
                $this->autoRender = false;  
                echo 'successful';
                }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The contact has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The contact could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "don't know how to set the response but to the user with additional data which i would have used" - It's hard to tell what is being asked here. Could you try re-phrasing it?

Answer (score 0):

sorry is if my question was wrongly phrased but i found the solution to my problems
i used the snippet below to grab the validation errors.

```
if($this->request->isAjax()){

        $this->autoRender = false;      
        if($this->Contact->validates()){

        }else{
        $error = implode($this->Contact->validationErrors;
        echo $error;


            }
        }
```

thanks all the same